# Typescript and material ui how fix type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm new in ts , please don't get mad on me. I got problem with material ui . Can't set type for `[classes[color + 'CardHeader']]: color`

Throws an error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<"cardHeader" | "cardHeaderPlain" | "warningCardHeader" | "successCardHeader" | "dangerCardHeader" | "infoCardHeader" | "primaryCardHeader", string>'.`

Could you please explain me , where I'm making a mistake?

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import useStyles from './styles/cardHeaderStyle';

type CardHeaderProps = {
  className: string,
  children: ReactNode,
  color: ColorType,
  plain?: boolean,
};

type ColorType = 'warning' | 'success' | 'danger' | 'info' | 'primary';

const CardHeader = (props: CardHeaderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { className = '', children, color, plain, ...rest } = props;
  console.log('classes', classes);

  const cardHeaderClasses = classNames({
    [classes.cardHeader]: true,
    // [classes['primaryCardHeader']]: color,
    [classes[color + 'CardHeader']]: color, 
    [classes.cardHeaderPlain]: plain,
    [className]: className !== undefined,
  });

  return (
    <div className={cardHeaderClasses} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardHeader;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you are using a sting literal in conjunction with a variable: `color + 'CardHeader'`.

TypeScript compiler won't know that you are/aren't giving it the appropriate string. I.e. what would happen if you replaced `'CardHeader'` with `'foo'`? None of the types would ever match up.

A potential solution would be to refactor your `ColorType` to include the `'CardHeader'` portion so it would look like:

`type ColorType = 'warningCardHeader' | 'successCardHeader' | 'dangerCardHeader' | 'infoCardHeader' | 'primaryCardHeader';`

This would now match with the `Record<"cardHeader" | "cardHeaderPlain" | "warningCardHeader" | "successCardHeader" | "dangerCardHeader" | "infoCardHeader" | "primaryCardHeader", string>` type.